# How to pass varying number of variables in a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hello everyone I am creating a translate function in javascript.

But I need to control the variables passed in this function, I need to pass multiple variables for example:

```
 translate("This is my word {variable} another words {variable2} and another one {variable3}", variable, variable2, variable3);
```

The number of variables may vary, is there a way to do this? Also if you put a down on this. Can you provide a comment which part you can't understand in my very simple question?

Comment: Are you looking for something like python format? If you simply want to use your variables in a string use the backtick notation  ```current = 5; console.log( `two + two = ${current}` )``` Notice the ` and not ```'``` or ```"```

Comment: Yes I understand but I want to have something similar with sprint in php like sprint("word %s words2 %s," variable1, variable2)

Comment: When defining the `translate` function, do it like this: `function translate(str, ...variables) { ... }`. `variables` will then be an array containing all the arguments, apart from the first argument (the string), the function was called with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few ways you could accept a varying number of variables in your function.

One way would be to use the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), where `string` will be the first argument and `values` will be an array containing all following arguments:

```js
function translate(string, ...values) {
  console.log(values)
}

translate("some string", "a", "b")
// output: ["a", "b"]
```

Without using ES6 syntax, you can use the arguments object, where `Array.from(arguments)` is an array containing all arguments passed to the function:

```js
function translate(string) {
  const args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1);
  console.log(args)
}

translate("some string", "a", "b")
// output: ["a", "b"]
```

With either of these methods, you'll be limited to inserting values into the string in the order in which they're passed in. If you wanted to be able to map variables to the string by name, like your example input string suggests, you could make your second parameter a params object, and pass a params object mapping the variables named in the string to desired values:

```js
function translate(string, params) {
  let resultString = string;
  for (const variableName in params) {
    resultString = resultString.replace(`{${variableName}}`,params[variableName]);
  }
  return resultString;
}

console.log(
  translate('{numerator} divided by {denominator} is {answer}', {
    numerator: 10,
    denominator: 2,
    answer: 5,
  })
);
// output: 10 divided by 2 is 5
```